# How do I test an ActionFilterAttribute with ASP.NET Web API?

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I'm building an ASP.NET Web API that uses a very simple action filter:

```
public class ValidateModelAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {
        if (actionContext.ModelState.IsValid == false) {
            var responseObject = new ApiResponse() {
                Errors = actionContext.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Select(e => e.ErrorMessage)
            };

            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, responseObject);
        }
    }
}
```

My action filter simply enforces that the `ModelState` is valid; if not, it returns a 400 with all the error messages so the client can do whatever they wish with the data.

Here is how I'm using the attribute in my controller:

```
[ValidateModelAttribute]
public HttpResponseMessage Db(DbModel model) {
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

I'm trying to test the attribute using Visual Studio's testing framework:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CaptureApiDatabase_IfRequiredFieldMissing_ReturnHttpBadRequest() {
    var controller = new ConfigureController();
    controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage();
    controller.Configuration = new HttpConfiguration();            

    var validationAttribute = new ValidateModelAttribute();
    validationAttribute.OnActionExecuting(controller.ActionContext);
    Assert.IsTrue(controller.ActionContext.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
```

This isn't working because I haven't provided the filter my data and as a result the `ModelState` is always valid.  How do I build a context so I can test this filter attribute?

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848137/how-can-you-unit-test-an-action-filter-in-asp-net-web-api

Comment: @Fals - I saw that question already, but the answer is just a copy and paste of Microsoft source code and doesn't demonstrate how to actually test the attribute.

Comment: It's complicated, you should isolate the attribute for testing. Simulate the entire request pipeline will be hard.

Comment: do you find a solution?