# Error while executing test, if using CreateResponse extention method to return Azure Function HttpResonseMessage

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

My Azure Function code is like below

```
public static class MyHttpTriggerFunction
{       
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        // some business logic

        if (valid)
        {
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, true);
        }
        else
        {
             return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "some error message");
        }            
    }
}
```

In my test project I am reading the result like below:

```
var result = await MyHttpTriggerFunction.Run(req, log).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

After executing the function, when it try to return the response in result variable, the test method fails with exception.

**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The request does not have an
>   associated configuration object or the provided configuration was
>   null.

**

I have made sure that test project has the same `System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtension` dll.

If I change the function  code not to use `CreateResponse` extension method (this extension method is from the VS 2017 template's code )
and return the response like below, I get the response in test method and  the test case  runs fine.

```
var res = new HttpResponseMessage();
if (valid)
{
    res.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    res.Content = new ObjectContent<bool>(true, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());        
    return res;
}
else
{
     res.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
     res.Content = new ObjectContent<string>("some error message", new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
     return res;
}
```

Below is the stacktrace of error

> Result StackTrace:     at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse[T](HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value, HttpConfiguration
>   configuration)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessageExtensions.CreateResponse[T](HttpRequestMessage
>   request, HttpStatusCode statusCode, T value)    at
>   MyFunctionApp.MyHttpTriggerFunction.d__1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at
>   MyFunctionAppUnitTest.MyHttpTriggerFunctionTest.d__2.MoveNext()
>   in
>   C:\Users\rsingh\Desktop\Git_Workspace\ActivationAPI\MyFunctionAppUnitTest\MyHttpTriggerFunctionTest.cs:line
>   53
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.MSTestAdapter.PlatformServices.ThreadOperations.ExecuteWithAbortSafety(Action
>   action) Result Message:    Test method
>   MyFunctionAppUnitTest.MyHttpTriggerFunctionTest.MyHttpTriggerFunction_SuccessResult
>   threw exception:  System.InvalidOperationException: The request does
>   not have an associated configuration object or the provided
>   configuration was null.

Am I missing something trivial

Comment: possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76252569/45583

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The Error message is telling you the problem.

> The request does not have an associated **configuration** object or the provided configuration was null.

When testing the request out side of a httpserver you need to give the request a `HttpConfiguration.`

```
// Arrange.
var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage();
request.Properties[System.Web.Http.Hosting.HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = configuration;

//...other code
```

Comment: Shame the error message doesn't tell us the solution, or that the configuration object is indeed expected inside that mysterious property bag there.

Comment: I'm getting this error while using postman in localhost. Is there any way to add the configuration there?

Answer (score 24):

This is not specific to Azure Functions, but in order to execute this test outside of the context of an actual HTTP request you need to make sure you create an `HttpConfiguartion` instance, configure it as required (e.g. add any formatters you may need) and call `SetConfiguration` on the `HttpRequestMessage` instance with that object.

Example:

```cs
var configuration = new HttpConfiguration();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage();
request.SetConfiguration(configuration);
```

Comment: Above worked for me. 1. Make sure to include System.Web.Http. 2. The adaption to make it work with the given code sample you should, prior to making the call to method CreateResponse, setting it up as: var configuration = new HttpConfiguration(); req.SetConfiguration(configuration);