# HTTP Azure Function UnitTest

Tags: c#, unit-testing, azure-functions

I have http Azure function and I'm writing unit test of that function. I'm getting below error

> Message: Test method Functions.Tests.CacheFunctionTests.CacheRefreshFunction threw exception: 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: The request does not have an associated configuration object or the provided configuration was null.

**UnitTest**

```
[TestMethod]
    public async Task CacheRefreshFunction()
    {
        // Arrange
        mockLog.Setup(x => x.Info(It.IsAny<string>()));
        mockService.Setup(x => x.RefreshCache()).Returns(Task.FromResult(0));
        HttpRequestMessage httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage() {
            RequestUri = new System.Uri("http://localhost:0895/CacheRefreshFunction"),
            Method = HttpMethod.Get                
        };            
        // Act
        await Functions.CacheRefreshFunction.Run(httpRequestMessage, mockRuleService.Object, mockLog.Object);

        // Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
```

I guess, I'm not passing some essential value in "HttpRequestMessage" property. Any idea?

Comment: guess you are missing configuration, like the error tells you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44447232/error-while-executing-test-if-using-createresponse-extention-method-to-return-a/44447349

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> System.InvalidOperationException: The request does not have an associated configuration object or the provided configuration was null.

As Jocke said, when testing the request out side of a httpserver you need to give the request a HttpConfiguration.

To fix this we need to add a `HttpConfiguration` object through the Properties dictionary as below:

```
Request = new HttpRequestMessage()
{
    Properties = { { HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey, new HttpConfiguration() } },
    RequestUri = new System.Uri("http://localhost:0895/RuleCacheRefreshFunction"),
    Method = HttpMethod.Get  
}
```

I added `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi` NuGet package to add `System.Web.Http.HttpConfiguration`